# UISplitViewController detailViewController subviews not resizing properly on orientation change

Tags: ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

HI,
I have the following setup in my iPad application:

UISplitViewController
DetailSide->
        SomeDetailViewController->
        Added subview as [SomeDetailViewController.view        addSubview:AnotherViewController.view]

1. Now after launching when the "AnotherViewController view" is displayed, its initial dimensions are always same of the last orientation(potrait/landscape view in interface builder) I saved that view XIB with, irrespective of the current device orientation.
2. Also On resetting the frame of the added subview(AnotherViewController.view) i.e  A. In -[SomeDetailViewController viewDidLoad] check for the current device orientation B. Set the frame of the AnotherViewController.view to match the required size. It doesnt resize appropriately thereafter(I have the springs/struts setup correctly in XIB autoresizing box) on orientation changes.
3. After doing step 2. above, I do see that around half of the AnotherViewController.view from bottom doesnt respond to any touches, looks like due to change in frame the responding co-ordinates get messed up.
4. I do have the "shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation" implemented to return YES for all the orientation in all my view controllers.

TIA.

Answer (score 0):

In XIB there will be an option to change the SPlitview Detail/Master in Inspector. Also if you add it as a subview you cannot get the splitview delegate methods, for that you will need to add it to window. Try removing all the elements from window using

[[[[UIAppDelegate window ] subviews] objectAtIndex:0] removeFromSuperview];
self.appDelegate.splitViewControllerObject = [[UISplitViewController alloc] init];

UINavigationController *rootNav = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:masterview];
UINavigationController *detailNav = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:detailview];

```
    self.appDelegate.splitViewControllerObject.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:rootNav, detailNav, nil];
    self.appDelegate.splitViewControllerObject.delegate = detailviewobj;

    [UIAppDelegate.window addSubview:self.appDelegate.splitViewControllerObject.view];
```

good luck....

Answer (score 0):

You should set autoresize properties to `AnotherViewController.view`:

> AnotherViewController.view.view.autoresizingMask
>   = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;